# Display function is not printing the values of link list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to make a c program to join two link list
But in the meanwhile  when I was printing the data of the link list after every insertion the list is not printing
I am hereby attaching the code

```
// Creating a menu deriv en program of single link list
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
   int data;
   struct node *next;
};

void main()
{
   struct node *a;
   char ch;
   struct node *temp;
   struct node *temp1;
   a=NULL;
   clrscr();
   do
   {
      if(a==NULL)
      {
         temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         printf("\nEnter Data\n");
         scanf("%d",&temp->data);
         temp->next=NULL;
         a=temp;
      }
      else
      {
         temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         temp->next=NULL;
         printf("\nEnter data element\n");
         scanf("%d",&temp->data);
         temp1=a;
         while(temp1->next!=NULL)
         {
            temp1=temp1->next;
         }
         temp1->next=temp;
      }
      printf("\nDo You Wish to continue\n");
      ch=getch();
   }while(ch=='Y'||ch=='y');
   printf("Do You Wish To See More Link List Operations");
   ch=getch();
   if(ch=='Y'||ch=='y')
   {
      printf("Press 1 For inserting node at the beginning of the list");
      ch=getch();
      switch(ch)
      case 1:
         temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         printf("Enter first data element");
         scanf("%d",&temp->data);
         temp1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         temp1=a;
         temp1=temp1->next;
         a=temp;
         temp=temp1;
   }

   printf("\nStatus of the link list\n");
   temp1=a;
   while(temp1!=NULL)
   {
      printf(" %d ",temp1->data);
      temp1=temp1->next;
   }
   getch();
}
```

Till now I have not written the code for joining two link list because first I want to get rid of this problem

Please Help!!!!

Comment: What excatly is problem ? It is not printing anything at all or not printing after every insertion ?

Comment: There's nothing that prints after every insertion. The code that prints the list contents is after the insertion loop.

Comment: OT: Urgently learn how to factor your code into functions. To reduce repeating essentially the same code multiple times and to aid readability.

Comment: after every insertion nothing is printing on the screen

Comment: See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). `temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);` is all that is required.

Comment: I am not getting where is the mistake in display function @DavidC.Rankin
Please Help!!!!

Comment: I haven't gone through you code in detail, but if you attempt to insert a node at the beginning of the list, you appear to break the list. For an existing list, to insert at the beginning, following `scanf`, you would do `temp->next = a; a = temp;` there is no need to allocate or use `temp1` in that exchange. You simply point the `->next` pointer to the existing list `a` and then reassign `a = temp;` so that `a` points to the new first node. If your list is correct, your display will work.

Answer (score 1):

Errors that I see:

**`switch` statement is not properly blocked**

You have:

```
  switch(ch)
  case 1:
     temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     printf("Enter first data element");
     scanf("%d",&temp->data);
     temp1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     temp1=a;
     temp1=temp1->next;
     a=temp;
     temp=temp1;
```

That is equivalent to:

```
  switch(ch)
  {
     case 1:
        temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  }

  printf("Enter first data element");
  scanf("%d",&temp->data);
  temp1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  temp1=a;
  temp1=temp1->next;
  a=temp;
  temp=temp1;
```

I suspect you intended to use:

```
  switch(ch)
  {
     case 1:
        temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter first data element");
        scanf("%d",&temp->data);
        temp1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp1=a;
        temp1=temp1->next;
        a=temp;
        temp=temp1;
  }
```

**Wrong label in `case`**

Since you are reading `1` into a `char`, you need to use:

```
    case '1':  // That is the character literal '1', not the integer literal 1
```

Comment: I havent used switch statement at all
Can you please tell me the problem in my code

Comment: @user6547375, I thought I pointed out exactly what the problems are and how to fix them.

Comment: Could you be more specific to which function the problem is?

Comment: @user6547375, I don't think I can be any more specific than what I wrote in the answer. I don't know how I can be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you are exercising `switch-case` code.
Operations in case statement are not correct.

```
....
case 1:
     temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     printf("Enter first data element");
     scanf("%d",&temp->data);
     temp1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     temp1=a;
     temp1=temp1->next;
     a=temp;
     temp=temp1;
...
```

It needs to simply add a new node at the start of the list. Can do so by

```
case 1:
     temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     printf("Enter first data element");
     scanf("%d",&temp->data);
     /*temp1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     temp1=a;*/
     temp->next = a;
     a=temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely going to pull your hair out mixing *numeric* and *character* input with `scanf`. `getch` is a non-portable bandaid that puts the keyboard in *raw* unbuffered mode that helps mask the problem, so you will do yourself a BIG favor if you simply learn how to handle user input correctly from the beginning.

The major drawback with `scanf` in taking mixed input is it leaves the `'\n'` in the input buffer. If you are only scanning numeric input, no problem because the numeric conversions skip leading *whitespace* (including the `'\n'`). However, the first time your ask for a *character* (e.g. `'y'` or `'Y'`) BAM, `scanf` happily takes the `'\n'` waiting in the input buffer as *your input*. Further, you can't tell if a number or character has been correctly read throughout your code because you never check the *return* for `scanf`.

Rather than trying to *duct-tape and bailing-wire* your `scanf` input routine together into a working form, just do user input right. Read each input with `fgets` (which reads the `'\n'` and solves the problem) and use `sscanf` to parse the input. ***[1]***, e.g.

```
    if (a == NULL) {
        temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);
        temp->next = NULL;
        printf (" Enter Data: ");
        /* do NOT mix character and numeric input with scanf UNLESS
         * you know EXACTLY what your are doing.
         */
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &temp->data) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid conversion.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        a = temp;
    } ...
```

After your input is straightened out, you can concentrate on your logic errors with adding a value at the beginning of the list. As I pointed out in the comment, all that is needed is to create the new node, and set the `->next` pointer to the existing list, and then set the list-address to that of the new node, e.g.:

```
    temp->next = a;
    a = temp;
```

Putting all those pieces together, and remembering to track and `free` the memory you have allocated, you could do something like the following with your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXC 64   /* constant (macro define) to use for buffer length */

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main (void)             /* main is type 'int' and returns a value */
{
    char buf[MAXC] = "";    /* if taking numeric & char input use fgets */
    struct node *a = NULL, *temp, *temp1;
    // clrscr ();           /* clrscr is non portable, only win has conio.h */
    do {
        if (a == NULL) {
            temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);
            temp->next = NULL;
            printf (" Enter Data: ");
            /* do NOT mix character and numeric input with scanf UNLESS
             * you know EXACTLY what your are doing.
             */
            if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &temp->data) != 1) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid conversion.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            a = temp;
        } else {
            temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);
            temp->next = NULL;
            printf (" Enter data element: ");
            if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &temp->data) != 1) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid conversion.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            temp1 = a;
            while (temp1->next != NULL) {
                temp1 = temp1->next;
            }
            temp1->next = temp;
        }
        printf (" Do You Wish to continue (y/n)?: ");
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid entry.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // ch = getch ();    /* getch is non-portable */
    } while (*buf == 'y' || *buf == 'Y');

    printf (" Do You Wish To See More Link List Operations (y/n)? ");
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid entry.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (*buf == 'y' || *buf != 'Y') {
        printf (" Press 1 For inserting node at the beginning of the list: ");
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid entry.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        switch (*buf) {
            case '1' :  temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);
                        printf (" Enter first data element: ");
                        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
                            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
                            return 1;
                        }
                        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &temp->data) != 1) {
                            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid conversion.\n");
                            return 1;
                        }
                        temp->next = a;
                        a = temp;
                        break;
            default :   fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid selection.\n");
        }
    }

    printf ("\nStatus of the link list\n");
    temp1 = a;
    while (temp1 != NULL) {
        printf (" %d ", temp1->data);
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    putchar ('\n');
    // getch ();     /* use getchar, getch is non-portable */

    temp = a;
    while (temp) {   /* free the memory you have allocated */
        struct node *victim = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        free (victim);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/lldisplay
 Enter Data: 2
 Do You Wish to continue (y/n)?: y
 Enter data element: 3
 Do You Wish to continue (y/n)?: y
 Enter data element: 4
 Do You Wish to continue (y/n)?: y
 Enter data element: 5
 Do You Wish to continue (y/n)?: n
 Do You Wish To See More Link List Operations (y/n)? y
 Press 1 For inserting node at the beginning of the list: 1
 Enter first data element: 1

Status of the link list
 1  2  3  4  5
```

Look things over and make sure you understand it, and let me know if you have any questions.

***footnotes:***

***1.*** you are not limited to only `sscanf` when parsing the line of text read as user-input, you can simply *walk a pointer* (or pair of pointers) down the string manually testing/parsing any combination of values you need. You can also use a pointer and walk the `strtoX` (e.g. `strtol`, `strtoul`, ...) functions down the line parsing numeric input as well (see *man strtol* and pay attention to the `**endptr` parameter). The key in the `fgets`/(then parse) approach is you ***decouple*** your read of input from the parsing of data allowing you to both (1) *validate* your read, and then also (2) *validate* your data rather than trying to do it all in one `scanf` call. There are uses for `scanf`, but taking alternating mixed *character* and *numeric* user-input isn't one of the recommended ones.